# UNABLE_TO_GET_ISSUER_CERT_LOCALLY error on yarn install

Tags: react-native, npm, yarnpkg, sentry

I get this error when I run `yarn install @sentry/react-native`

```
Error: Unable to download sentry-cli binary from https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-cli/releases/download//1.71.0/sentry-cli-Darwin-universal.
Error code: UNABLE_TO_GET_ISSUER_CERT_LOCALLY
```

I have tried `yarn config set strict-ssl false -g` and `yarn config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/` and both have failed.

Comment: any solution for this?